# Migrating Multi Server Office to G Cloud

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I have a client who is operating with 2 physical Windows servers:

1 Active Directory
1 Application Server, which runs 1 Hyper-V Terminal Server inside

If we do a CloudEndure migration to G Cloud, will the Hyper-V translate and run? Does G Cloud support nested virtualization in Windows? Or do we need to migrate the Terminal Server as a 3rd server into the cloud and remove Hyper-V from the Application Server before migrating that server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to have Nested Windows machines in Google Cloud, as explains Microsoft in this [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization) it is required an Intel processor with VT-x and EPT technology, and Google Cloud Platform has it.

In the following [Google Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances) does not appear any Windows VM as tested but I saw a lot of people using Windows Nested virtual machine in the Google Cloud.

For that, create the nested virtual machine IMAGE with the "licenses flag" as follow:

```
gcloud compute images create nested-vm-image \
  --source-disk disk1 --source-disk-zone us-central1-b \
  --licenses "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/vm-options/global/licenses/enable-vmx"
```

and then, create the virtual machine based in the previous image with at least a "Intel Haswell" CPU (or newer) as requirement:

```
gcloud compute instances create example-nested-vm --zone us-central1-b \
          --min-cpu-platform "Intel Haswell" \
          --image nested-vm-image
```